# Defining layer style for KML layer within OGR Virtual Format?

Tags: kml, style, ogr2ogr, vrt

I have the following OGR virtual format data source, which includes a few GeoJSON files and one KML file:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
  <OGRVRTUnionLayer name="union">

    <GeometryType>wkbGeometryCollection</GeometryType>
    <LayerSRS>EPSG:4326</LayerSRS>

    <OGRVRTLayer name="AMDT_02_2014_Finland_FIR">
      <SrcDataSource>AMDT_02_2014_Finland_FIR.kml</SrcDataSource>
      <SrcSQL>SELECT *,'PEN(c:#FF00FF,w:10px)' AS OGR_STYLE FROM AMDT_02_2014_Finland_FIR</SrcSQL>
    </OGRVRTLayer>

    <OGRVRTLayer name="OGRGeoJSON">
      <SrcDataSource>tsa2014.js</SrcDataSource>
      <SrcSQL>SELECT *,'PEN(c:#00FFFF,w:10px)' AS OGR_STYLE FROM OGRGeoJSON</SrcSQL>
    </OGRVRTLayer>

    <OGRVRTLayer name="OGRGeoJSON">
      <SrcDataSource>ctr2014.js</SrcDataSource>
      <SrcSQL>SELECT *,'PEN(c:#FFFF00,w:5px)' AS OGR_STYLE FROM OGRGeoJSON</SrcSQL>
    </OGRVRTLayer>

  </OGRVRTUnionLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Setting the layer style for the GeoJSON layers works fine when doing a `ogr2ogr` conversion to another format such as PDF. However, trying to set the KML layer style with `<SrcSQL>SELECT *,'PEN(c:#FF00FF,w:10px)' AS OGR_STYLE FROM AMDT_02_2014_Finland_FIR</SrcSQL>` seems to have no effect. Default black pen is used to draw the polygon outline:

[image: Example output of the three layers]

Is there a way to change the style of a KML layer within OGR VRT file? At least the syntax above does not seem to work.

The KML file used in this question can be downloaded from [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/m8e1n2d5r6pr7r0/AAAT351VmCiNktLV7Eqp7t-Ta/KML?dl=0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear you are out of luck with your current approach because this sentence from the GDAL wiki http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/KML makes me understand that the GDAL KML driver does not support OGR Styles:

> **Styling**
>
> Until the driver supports the OGR simple feature style...

The same wiki page gives advice for styling KML with XLS stylesheet. Consider to make a feature request about adding OGR_STYLE support for the KML driver into GDAL issue tracker http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/. Check the old tickets first, though.