# Applying styling to KML (from a shp) using ogr2ogr?

Tags: shapefile, kml, ogr2ogr, style

Is it possible to generate a styled KML using ogr2ogr (ie pen width and colour?) I cannot seem to find anything in the ogr2ogr documentation.

My code so far is;

```
ogr2ogr.exe -f "KML" prow-kml.kml "C:\prow.shp"
```

Unfortunately this just gives me a default colour line when viewing in Google Earth.

Comment: The KML page for OGR (http://www.gdal.org/drv_kml.html) says: "Limited support is available for fills, line color and other styling attributes. Please try a few sample files to get a better sense of actual behavior."  So that is the limit of the guaranteed behaviour. In addition, there isn't interoperable line colouring in shapefile variations, so you'd need to say what specific source you're using.

Comment: see this thread : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123710/how-to-define-layer-style-for-kml-layer-within-ogr-virtual-format